# Should a view controller within a container view dismiss itself or its parent?

Tags: ios

If a view controller A is modally presented and it contains a container view containing a view controller B.
Then if B wishes to dismiss itself (which in effect is also effectively dismissing A because B is contained within A) then should B call self.dismiss() or self.parent?.dismiss()?

Comment: In my opinion, in the current situation, B shouldn't know if he's been presented or not. I think A should know everything about the navigation. (An yes I assume the controller is a `he`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since B is a separate entity and B may not necessarily be contained in A, if B wishes to dismiss itself, it can call `self.dismiss()`.

There will be 2 cases. If B is presented by itself, then it would dismiss as usual. If B is contained, then the OS would see that it's contained within A, then dismiss A.

However, if the only use of B is to be contained in A, then it makes sense to let A handle the navigation. The part where B "wishes" for itself to be dismissed can be done using delegates or blocks.